# i18next, where does language code (ja-JP) comes from? and How can I simulate If I come from another language?

Tags: node.js, i18next

Following the example form [i18next-express-middleware](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-express-middleware)

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {

  var lng = req.language;

  console.log("");
  console.log("Current language:", lng);
  console.log("");

  res.render("account/login",{layout:"layout-account"});
});
```

form the terminal I got : **Current language: ja-JP** , which is cool, 
but where does the **ja-JP** comes from (windows or browser's language settings?)

I can use **req.i18n.changeLanguage('en');** to change language to see if translation is good or not, 
but, how can I simulate If I come from another language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/i18next/i18next-express-middleware#language-detection there in the order you can set from where to detect and in which priority.

request your page with ?lng=en to simulate